# WSO2 LDAP Connector can't search object category Computer

Tags: ldap, wso2, ldap-query, wso2-esb

I'm exposing specific set of LDAP queries as an API in WSO2 ESB. I'm using LDAP Connector for this(https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/LDAP+Connector).

I could successfully expose below LDAP query.

```
{
    "providerUrl":"ldap://xx.x.xxx.xx:xxxx",
    "securityPrincipal":"CN=LdapUser,OU=Service Accounts,OU=ATC atcName,DC=company,DC=com",
    "securityCredentials":"pass_goes_here",
    "secureConnection":"false",
    "disableSSLCertificateChecking":"false",
    "application":"ldap",
    "operation":"searchEntity",
   "content":{
        "dn":"DC=company,DC=com",
        "objectClass":"user",
        "attributes":"sAMAccountName",
        "filters":"(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=ykarunarathna))"
    }
}

Respose:
{
  "result": {
    "entry": {
      "dn": "CN=Yasas Karunarathna,OU=xxxxxx,OU=xxxxxxx,OU=ATC atcName,DC=company,DC=com",
      "sAMAccountName": "ykarunarathna"
    }
  }
}
```

But when i tried below LDAP search it gives null results

```
{
    "providerUrl":"ldap://xx.x.xxx.xx:xxxx",
    "securityPrincipal":"CN=LdapUser,OU=Service Accounts,OU=ATC atcName,DC=company,DC=com",
    "securityCredentials":"pass_goes_here",
    "secureConnection":"false",
    "disableSSLCertificateChecking":"false",
    "application":"ldap",
    "operation":"searchEntity",
    "content":{
       "dn":"DC=company,DC=com",
       "objectClass":"Computer",
       "attributes":"cn",
       "filters":"(&(extensionattribute15=*)(objectCategory=CN=Computer,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=com))"
    }
}

Response:
{
    "result": null
}
```

While the same query returns valid results when I try it in C# code.

```
(&(extensionattribute15=*)(objectCategory=CN=Computer,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=company,DC=com))
```

Am I missing something? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to investigate this since the issues is related to custom ldap setup. I assume you have used searchEntry operation. We are internally using Java for this and you can find the relevant code in following url.

https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-ldap/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/connector/ldap/SearchEntry.java

Can you try to debug in your environment?